# Checking for existence of $firebaseObject

Tags: firebase, angularfire

For a normal Javascript object on $scope, you might use ngShow with a div to make the div's presence depend on the existence of the object.

```
$scope.myObj = null;
// And then later
$scope.myObj = {arbitrary:{number:{of:"objects"}}};
...
<div ng-show="myObj">{{myObj}}</div>
```

But if you tie an object to a $firebaseObject

```
var fbObjRef = new Firebase(FirebaseURL).child("fbObj")
$scope.myObj = $firebaseObject(fbObjRef);
```

Then your ngShow won't work because a reference that is empty in Firebase will still be represented client side by an object that looks like:

```
{
  "$id":"fbObj",
  "$priority":null,
  "$value":null
}
```

And then later if non-primitive content is set at that reference, the $value key disappears and is replaced by the content:

```
{
  "$id":"fbObj",
  "$priority":null,
  "someKey":{
    "anotherKey":"someValue"
  }
}
```

What's the best way to check against the existence of the $firebaseObject? Here's what I'm doing but it feels clunky. Maybe this is an opportunity to add an $exists key to the AngularFire API.

```
<div ng-show="myObjExists()">{{myObj}}</div>
...
$scope.myObjExists = function(){
  return !(
    $scope.myObj.hasOwnProperty("$value")
    && $scope.myObj.$value === null
  );
};
```

Comment: `<div ng-show="myObj.someKey.anotherKey">{{myObj}}</div>`?

Comment: Sure but I want the div to be agnostic about what myObj contains, whether it's someKey, thisKey, thatKey, a primitive value, or even all of the above.

Comment: So listen for changes in the object (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-watchcallback-context) and use that to set a `$scope.isDivShowing` based on the `$value`.

Comment: I think that ends up surpassing the clunkiness of what I'm already doing. The Angular expression is already doing what the new $watch code would do, and you'd still have to check on the existence and value of $value. It would be nice if controller code wasn't necessary. I think I'll make a feature request. Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case here? We don't know if the data will be an object or a primitive ahead of time? What sort of UI are we building? Also, we're trying to treat a asynchronously loaded, remote set of data as a local POJO that we can just ping any time to see if it has been set. This should be clunky. Also, seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What's the real use case and constraints?